# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature when uploading multiple images from react-native

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-native, activerecord

When i upload 2 images from react native application using the code below

```
        const onSubmit = async (values) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("claim[category_id]", category);
            formData.append("claim[client_id]", client);
            formData.append("claim[location]", JSON.stringify(location));
            formData.append("claim[comment]", values.comment);
            formData.append("claim[forwarded]", "false");
            formData.append("claim[user_id]", user.id);
            for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
              formData.append("claim[images][]", images[i]);
            }
            if (
              values.category &&
              values.client &&
              values.location &&
              images.length === 2
            ) {
              const response = await axios.post(`${GENERAL_URL}/claims`, formData, {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
              });
              const { success, claims } = response.data;
              if (success) {
                dispatch(addClaim(claims));
                Alert.alert("CONFIRMATION", "The Claim has been submitted", [
                  null,
                  { text: "OK", onPress: () => navigation.navigate("Explore") },
                ]);
              } else {
                alert("Oops! something went wrong, please try again");
              }
            } else {
              alert("Please fill in all fields");
            }
          };
```

I am getting the error log below:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/claims" for 172.71.146.145 at 2023-07-06 11:21:52 +0000
Processing by Api::V1::ClaimsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"claim"=>{"images"=>["file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fclaimsapp-e6f181ad-9716-464f-b689-fa016d86a564/Camera/8368dd02-db36-4fac-a411-b221e2e59cbb.jpg", "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fclaimsapp-e6f181ad-9716-464f-b689-fa016d86a564/Camera/e23136d2-b43a-4797-a626-50d0f917b896.jpg"], "category_id"=>"1", "client_id"=>"2", "location"=>"{\"altitude\":-13.300000190734863,\"heading\":0,\"latitude\":40.3746823,\"longitude\":49.8341172,\"altitudeAccuracy\":5.68895149230957,\"speed\":0,\"accuracy\":22.576000213623047}", "comment"=>"Test", "forwarded"=>"false", "user_id"=>"1"}}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 290ms (ActiveRecord: 14.3ms | Allocations: 10572)
FATAL -- : [d8db3e20-d76c-4258-a7db-fb13428d4a2f]
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):
app/controllers/api/v1/claims_controller.rb:40:in `create'
```

My rails api is as below

```
        def create
          @api_v1_claim = Claim.new(api_v1_claim_params)

          if @api_v1_claim.save
            updated_claims = Claim.where(user_id: @api_v1_claim.user_id)
            render json: { success: true, claims: updated_claims, code: 2201 }
          else
            render json: @api_v1_claim.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end

        private

        def api_v1_claim_params
          params.require(:claim).permit(:comment, :location, :forwarded, :user_id, :client_id, :category_id, images: [])
        end
```

My model is:

```
        class Claim < ApplicationRecord
          belongs_to :user
          belongs_to :client
          belongs_to :category

          has_many_attached :images

          def image_urls
            if images.attached?
              images.map do |image|
                Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image, only_path: true)
              end
            end
          end

        end
```

My ClaimSerializer is:

```
class ClaimSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :id, :location, :comment, :forwarded, :category_id, :user_id, :client_id, :images, :image_urls
end
```

I am using ruby 3.1.3p185 and Rails 7.0.6. The client app i am using react native expo.

I have deployed my rails api on render.com and all other functionalities are working. the only problem is the image upload part.

I dont know where i am getting it wrong